# Sort By Products By Creation Date in EE with SOLR

Tags: magento-enterprise, sorting, solr

I need to sort product collection by creation date. It's static attribute in the product entity table. SOLR can index and sort by eav attributes. One option is to create a new attribute and copy date on product save event.  Any other suggestions?  Ideas what is the best way to add custom data to the SOLR index?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to the product `created_at` and `updated_at` attributes, then simply commenting out the `->addVisibleFilter()` in the Catalog Product Attribute Grid in the admin and simply set the Search and Sort fields to Yes, and re-index, you'll notice the date(s) are now in the `catalogsearch_fulltext` table which the Enterprise Solr will recognize and add the data to its doc records as well.

**NOTE:** Don't forgot to remove the core code change or do it via local code pool obviously if you like.

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Grid extends Mage_Eav_Block_Adminhtml_Attribute_Grid_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Prepare product attributes grid collection object
     *
     * @return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Attribute_Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_attribute_collection');
            //->addVisibleFilter();
        $this->setCollection($collection);

        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }
```

After this you'll want to let Solr know its a sortable metadata field.

**Enterprise/Search/Model/Adapter/Abstract.php** you'll notice:

```
/**
 * Store common Solr metadata fields
 * All fields, that come up from search engine will be filtered by these keys
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $_usedFields = array('sku', 'visibility', 'in_stock');
```

You may want to also look over the method: `_prepareIndexProductData` in

**Enterprise/Search/Model/Adapter/Abstract.php**

```
/**
 * Prepare index data for using in search engine metadata.
 * Prepare fields for advanced search, navigation, sorting and fulltext fields for each search weight for
 * quick search and spell.
 *
 * @param array $productIndexData
 * @param int $productId
 * @param int $storeId
 *
 * @return  array|bool
 */
protected function _prepareIndexProductData($productIndexData, $productId, $storeId)
```

I've only tested the ability to edit the "non-visible" attributes and confirmed the addition to the fulltext table, I don't have Solr running locally at the moment to test it, but in theory should work without any need to mirror redundant data.

Hope this helps!